# Range Partition Table creation using Job Config in Bigquery

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

Trying to read a csv file into dataframe and use that dataframe to load into a Bigquery Table with Range Partitioning. But getting a 400 POST Invalid value for Long:  is not the correct type error.

Steps to reproduce:
Using google-cloud-bigquery v1.24.0

```
Test.csv

Name, Age, DOB
"rona", 10, 01-01-2010
"king", 20, 05-01-2000
```

Here is the code to replicate

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery

def Range_Partitioning(field, dict_range):
    cRangePartition = bigquery.RangePartitioning(range_=bigquery.PartitionRange(start=dict_range.get("Start"), interval=dict_range.get("Interval"), end=dict_range.get("End")),
                field=field)
    return cRangePartition

df = pd.read_csv("Test.txt", dtype={ "Name": "str", "Age": "int64", "DOB": "str"}, parse_dates=["DOB"])
BQClient = bigquery.Client()
Dataset = "Test"
TableName = "Load_Range_Test"
schema = [
    {
        "name": "Name",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "Age",
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    },
    {
        "name": "DOB",
        "type": "DATE",
        "mode": "REQUIRED"
    }
]
TableRef = sProjectId + "." + Dataset + "." + TableName
RangePartition = Range_Partitioning("Age", {"start":0,  "interval":1, "end":100})
WriteOption = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
JobConfig = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
                    schema=schema,
                    write_disposition=WriteOption,
                    range_partitioning=RangePartition)
Job = BQClient.load_table_from_dataframe(df, TableRef, job_config=JobConfig)
Job.result()
```

Error: 
400 POST Invalid value for Long:  is not the correct type

Works when I don't do a range partitioning, only with Range partitioning I am getting this error.

Comment: Are you sure you can call [`bigquery.RangePartitioning`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.RangePartitioning.html#google-cloud-bigquery-table-rangepartitioning) that way? The function signature says it accepts two arguments: (`range_`: [_`bigquery.PartitionRange`_](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.PartitionRange.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.PartitionRange), `field_`: _str_)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado you are right, I forgot to add the method I created, updated the code. I did use the range_ and field as per BQ documentation.

Comment: What's `sPartitionColumn` in your function?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, is field, which would be "Age" which is an integer

Comment: Ok great :) thanks for the edits! Now your code makes sense to me - and I don't actually know the answer - this seems confusing to me too. Does your code run smoothly straight through exactly as it's shown here in your post? After these edits hopefully it will be much easier for someone else to come along and help out!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado yeah you would just need to change the ProjectId and have proper credentials to run a BQ job. It should run and give the same error posted.

Comment: @Kishan Kumar, Do you still observe this error?

Comment: @mk_sta, Yes I am still observing this, would you know what mistake am making?

Answer (score 0):

I've done the code works correctly omitting `Range_Partitioning(field, dict_range)` function usage, explicitly specifying [*bigquery.RangePartitioning*](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.RangePartitioning.html#google-cloud-bigquery-table-rangepartitioning) parameters :

```
RangePartition = bigquery.RangePartitioning(
field="Age",
range_=bigquery.PartitionRange(start=0, end=100, interval=1)
)
WriteOption = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
JobConfig = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
                    schema=schema,
                    write_disposition=WriteOption,
                    range_partitioning=RangePartition)
Job = BQClient.load_table_from_dataframe(df, TableRef, job_config=JobConfig)
Job.result()
```

Seems to be `cRangePartition` returns inconsistent range values.